# Unbounded self-adjoint operator with compact resolvent: Expansion

Tags: spectral-theory, compact-operators, unbounded-operators

Given an unbounded self-adjoint operator $T\colon H \supset \mathrm{dom}(T) \to H$ on a Hilbert space $H$ with compact resolvent, i.e. $T$ has a purely discrete spectrum, the eigenfunctions $e_n$ form an orthonormal basis of $H,$ the eigenvalues $\lambda_n \in \mathbb R$ with $|\lambda_n | \to \infty$ and $Te_n = \lambda_n e_n$ for $n \in \mathbb N.$ My question: Does a representation

$$Tx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n (x,e_n)_H e_n$$

for $x \in \mathrm{dom}(T) \subset H$ hold as for compact operators?

Thanks!

EDIT: I think that the answer is quite simple:

Let $x \in \mathrm{dom}(T) \subset H$ be fixed. It holds $Tx \in H$ and hence $Tx$ can be represented by

$$Tx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (Tx,e_n)_H e_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (x,Te_n)_H e_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n (x,e_n)_H e_n.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: It should be exactly the content of the spectral theorem in this particular case. Also, $x\in\mathrm{dom}(T)$ should be equivalent to the sum $\sum |\lambda_n (x, e_n)|^2$ being finite. I say "should" because I am not really checking it, I am just relying on my memory and intuition.

Comment: I think so too, because the Spectral Theorem states with the unique spectral measure $E_T$ that

$$ T = \int_{\mathbb R} \lambda \mathrm d E_T(\lambda).$$

Comment: For $x \in \mathrm{dom} (T)$ this gives
$$ Tx = \int_{\mathbb R} \lambda \, \mathrm d E_T(\lambda)x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n (x,e_n)_H e_n.$$
Right?

Comment: That's what I thought.